# how to set a default value using sequelize and mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a active column, created in my model and migration file as below, this creates a tinyint column in mysql table, but doesn't set the default value. I tried changing the type to Sequelize.TINYINT(1) and
defaulValue to '0'. it still doesn't set the default value. what am i doing wrong here?

```
  active: {
         type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
          allowNull: false,
          defaulValue: false
      }
```

Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.15.0, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.21.7]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misspelled defaul**t**Value

```
active: {
         type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
          allowNull: false,
          defaultValue: false
      }
```